# PHP - Pass variable to one domain and back again

Tags: php

I am in need of passing a variable from one domain to another and then grabbing the results from the second domain and passing it back. I have not done this before so any help would be great.

Basically, the first domain would contain a key. For example:

```
$key = '1234567890123456';
```

I would like to send that variable to the second domain which would validate if that key exists in the database and let the first domain know if it does or not. I already have the code for the second domain which would check the key to see if it exists.

However, I am not sure the best way to send the above variable to the second domain and grab the response from the second domain and send it back.

Since this is not a form and should just be triggered once the page is loaded, I don't know the best method to do that.

Any help and guidance on that would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: how do you want/need to send data? POST, GET or what, details please

Comment: do you want direct server-to-server communications? or bounce this through client-side?

Comment: Hello guys, great questions. @MarcB I'm not sure the best method to do it. I was hoping for suggestions. Any code ideas and suggestions are welcomed! I know it will not be POST OR GET since there is no form to be submitted. The first domain should automatically send this info to the second one. I also have not used API in the past.

Comment: Have you tried `include`, `include_once`, `require`, or `require_once`?

Comment: I have not tried that. Are you suggesting that would be the best way to communicate back and forth between the two domains?

Comment: using POST or GET method doesn't mean it should be html form. Use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) or [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if you submit data by GET method.

Comment: Thanks! I never had any reason to use POST outside of a form so I didn't know you could do that. Wow, learn something everyday lol. Can you show a quick example of how you would do it with either method? Thanks

Comment: You could use Web Services with PHP SOAP . Links that might be helpful : http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php , http://www.joelhainley.com/index.php/2008/03/03/php-soap-a-simple-php-web-service-example/ , http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/

Comment: @Uours Thanks, however, I have never used SOAP in the past so all that looks pretty foreign to me. Otherwise, probably a good method. Thanks though!

Comment: @Stichoza I just tried the file_get_contents() function and that works great! Question, how do you send POST data versus GET? I can use GET and ?key=somethinghere however, I would like to use POST instead. Also, please submit your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: NVM, I used curl to achieve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply send **GET** data by [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Example:

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://example.com/script.php?var1=value1&var2=value2");
```

And here is a very simple code to send **POST** data to a URL with [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/script.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "var1=value1&var2=value2");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Source: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/simplepost.html